# how does PagedListAdapter in Android decide the order of list?

Tags: android, pagedlist, android-paging

android introduced a new component that provides easier implementation of paged list. when reading up the tutorial on how to use [PagedListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedListAdapter), couple things I still don't understand. if `DiffUtil.ItemCallback` was implemented to place rows correctly in the list, how does `PagedListAdapter` know the order of items to display? I see the example only calls `submitList()`. assume the example didn't have `ASC` in the query.

I thought the advantage of using `PagedListAdater` was to place item at any position like what google demonstrated [image]

also another question is how we handle config change(like device rotation)? The example google provides doesn't seem like it keeps a copy of the data anywhere. It grabs data from database, signal all the observers then pass new list of data directly to `PagedListAdapter`. Unless the adapter can survive during device rotation.

Comment: In the case of room, does it use the Primary key if an order is not specified?